# Running out of memory with merge

Tags: r

I have a paneldata which looks like:

(Only the substantially cutting for my question)

```
Persno 122 122 122 333 333 333 333 333 444 444 
Income 1500 1500 2000 2000 2100 2500 2500 1500 2000 2200
year 1990 1991 1992 1990 1991 1992 1993 1994 1992 1993
```

Now I would like to give out for every row (PErsno) the years of workexperience at the begining of the year.  I use `ddply`

```
hilf3<-ddply(data, .(Persn0), summarize, Bgwork = 1:(max(year) - min(year)))
```

To produce output looking like this:

```
Workexperience: 1 2 3 1 2 3 4 5 1 2
```

Now I want to merge the `ddply` results to my original panel data:

```
data<-(merge(data,hilf3,by.x="Persno",by.y= "Persno"))
```

The panel data set is very large. The code stops because of a memory size error.

Errormessage:

1: In make.unique(as.character(rows)) :

Reached total allocation of 4000Mb: see help(memory.size)

What should I do?

Comment: In which line of code do you run out of memory?  `ddply` or `merge`?

Comment: @ Andrie the link of the questiuon you posted , i asked yesterday.

Comment: with merge i want to connect the results of the ddply code to my "origin" paneldata. im merge i do run out of memory.

Comment: In that case your question was misleading.  I have rewritten it.  Please let me know if this doesn't reflect what you mean.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Re-reading your question, I think you don't actually want to use `merge` here at all. Just sort your original data frame and rbind Bgwork from hilf3. And also, your `ddply`-call could perhaps result in a `1:0` sequence, which is most likely not what you want. Try

```
data = data[order(data$Persno, data$year),]
hilf3 = ddply(data, .(Persno), summarize, Bgwork=(year - min(year) + 1))
stopifnot(nrow(data) == nrow(hilf3))
stopifnot(all(data$Persno == hilf3$Persno))
data$Bgwork = hilf3$Bgwork
```

Answer (score 5):

Well, perhaps the surest way of fixing this is to get more memory. However, this isn't always an option. What you can do is somewhat dependent on your platform. On Windows, check the results of `memory.size()`and compare this to your available RAM. If memory size is lower than RAM then you can increase it. This is not an option on linux, as by default it will show all of your memory.

Another issue that can complicate matters is whether or not you are running a 32bit or 64bit system, as 32bit windows can only address up to a certain amount of RAM (2-4GB) depending on [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is not an issue if you are using 64bit Windows 7, which can address far more memory.

A more practical solution is to eliminate all unnecessary objects from your workspace before performing merge. You should run `gc()` to see how much memory you have and are using, and also to remove any objects which have no more references. Personally, I would probably run your `ddply()` from a script, then save the resulting dataframe as a CSV file, close your workspace and reopen it and then perform the merge again.

Finally the worst possible option (but which does require a whole lot less memory) is to create a new dataframe, and use the subsetting commands in R to copy the columns you want over, one by one. I really don't recommend this as it is tiresome and error prone, but I have had to do it once when there was no way to complete my analysis otherwise (i ended up investing in a new computer with more RAM shortly afterwards).

Hope this helps.

Comment: @ richiemorrisroe Thank you for the detailed reply.But I hope that there might be another approach to solve my problem. Subset is a option but it would take too long.

Comment: @ Andre what system are you running? If you have 4+Gb of RAM and a 32bit system on Windows, you might be best served by installing a linux partition and using this to complete the data formatting challenge. I suppose you could also use the unix filesystem tools i.e. cat etc to put the two files together

Comment: @ richiemorrisroe Windwos 7 x64 with 4 gb RAM, perhaps it`s the best idea to install a linux partition.

Comment: @Andre - did you check memory.size()? If your memory size is at 4gb already, then the Linux partition won't help with RAM. It will however, help with command line tools to do some of this outside R, and of course freedom. Beautiful, beautiful freedom.

Comment: Apart from my memory problem, maybe there is another way to give out the workexperience without merge and ddply ?

Comment: @Andre - see the response of otsaw. Although I've never tried it, that approach looks like it could work well.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to merge large data frames in R, one good option is to do it in pieces of, say 10000 rows. If you're merging data frames x and y, loop over 10000-row pieces of x, merge (or rather use `plyr::join`) with y and immediately append these results to a sigle csv-file. After all pieces have been merged and written to file, read that csv-file. This is very memory-efficient with proper use of logical index vectors and well placed `rm` and `gc` calls. It's not fast though.

Comment: @ otsaw sounds not bad. But I´m still hope there is maybe another easy way to give out the workexperience without merge and ddply ?

Comment: @Andre Have you tried [data.table](http://datatable.r-forge.r-project.org/)?  I'll post an answer if you can provide a way to generate dummy data of the same size you have.

Comment: @ Matthew Dowle what do you mean with dummy data? I used read.table to work with my paneldataset.

Comment: @ otsaw WOKRS!, to solve the merge problem, but your las comment is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, the `data.table` package has provided a re-implementation of data frames and a `merge` function that I have found to be much more memory-efficient than R's default. Converting the default data frames to data tables with `as.data.table` may avoid memory issues.